# How to retrieve unpaired Bluetooth device model number

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I recently coded an Android Application and succeeded to retrieving the Bluetooth device names and mac address. However, this Bluetooth device name is variable and users can change it by changing their device name in settings. The names i retrieved were like "unknown", "Tom's iPhone",etc. I need their device model number specifically such as "SM-S908E". Is it possible to retrieve this information through bluetooth?

Comment: You might be able to find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393885/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-device-model-name

Comment: @MennoSpijker Does the BluetoothDevice contain information about the device model? I couldn't find it in the documentation

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan same

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the [Device Information Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/device-information-service-1-1/)

The Device Information Service may expose one or more of these characteristics

- Manufacturer Name
- Model Number
- Serial Number
- Hardware Revision
- Firmware Revision
- Software Revision
- System ID
- IEEE 11073-20601 Regulatory Certification Data List
- PnP ID